Contour integral with Bose-Einstein function and a Lorentzian function
I am trying to solve the following integral using Contour method. Any suggestions about the contour?
$\int_0^\infty dw w\frac{n(w)}{(w-w_0)^2+\Gamma^2}$
where $n(w)=(e^{\beta \hbar w}-1)^{-1}$ and $\Gamma,w_0>0$. I saw a very promising method here (Contour for Principal Value Integral) that involves introducing $log(z)$ in the function. However, I have two problems with that contour: one, I am not able to show that the integral vanishes on the bigger Contour as $R\to\infty$, and the second is the issue with the sum of infinite residues on the imaginary contour which does not give a real quantity (the integral is real). Thanks for any help.
